# Coroutine still running even if game is paused and time scale set to 0

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title pointed out, for some reason when my game is paused my co-routine still runs. I even went as far as to put the time scale condition in a while condition so that the while doesnt run if it paused but to no avail. I've added my code in it's entirety and hope that someone will be able to assist.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Chronos;

public class ObjectSpawn : BaseBehaviour //MonoBehaviour
{

    public float minTime = 3f;
    public float maxTime = 9f;
    public float minX = -65.5f;
    public float maxX = -5.5f;
    public float topY = -5.5f;
    public float z = 0.0f;
    public int count = 50;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public bool doSpawn = true;

    public float fallGrav =1.0f;
    int first = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        Clock clock = Timekeeper.instance.Clock("MovingOneWayPlatforms");

        StartCoroutine(Spawner());

    }



    IEnumerator Spawner()
    {
        while (first == 1) {
                yield return time.WaitForSeconds(8.0f);
                first = 0;
            } 
        while (doSpawn   && count > 0 /*&& time.timeScale != 0 */)
        {

            Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            float min = renderer.bounds.min.x;
            float max = renderer.bounds.max.x;
            Vector3 v12 = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), this.gameObject.transform.position.y, 0f);

            prefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = fallGrav;
            prefab =  Instantiate(prefab, v12, Random.rotation);

            count--; 
           //  yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minTime, maxTime)); 
              yield return time.WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minTime, maxTime));

             Destroy(prefab, 6);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with `time.WaitForSeconds(...)`. What happens if you replace that with `new WaitForSeconds(...)`?

Comment: @ThomasHilbert the first while is actually not the issue, I can comment it and it's actually the same.

Comment: I found an answer in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/coroutine-continues-to-run-while-game-is-paused.460205/) (3rd post by pienelio). My guess would be that you are stuck in the `WaitForSeconds` which doesn't work when timeScale is 0.

Comment: @Niana What do you mean by "still running" ? Which part is still running and what exactly do you expect when you pause? The coroutine should stop or be able to resume?Your question is lacking some details

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Chronos package, but I would assume that this is where the issue originates. Make sure timeScale really is 0, for example by adding a `Debug.Log(Time.timeScale)` into your loop. If necessary, go pure Unity (no Chronos package) and see if it works if you set `Time.timeScale` to 0 directly, and use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(...)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment your 2nd while statement, I think that is your problem.

Comment: The comment is not the problem, I just commented it to test, even with the code not commented it still does not stop

Answer (score 0):

I am new and still not used to Chronos.
Maybe I'm wrong but my guess is this line.

`Destroy(prefab, 6);`

In my understanding, Destroy's delay should not affected by chronos.
You better use new Coroutine to destroy it.

like this

```
StartCoroutine(DestroyRoutine(prefab))

IEnumurator DestroyRoutine(GameObject gameobject)
{
   yield return time.WaitForSeconds(6);
   Destroy(gameObject)    
}
```